# Heuristics for modeling a convolutional network

Tags: conv-neural-network, convolution

Is there some good heuristics to choose:

- Number of filters in a Convolutional layer
- Size of the filters
- Number of Convolutional layers

I have **250k** small images (**28x28**), and I have **37 outputs**.
So I don't know if knowing this can help me to choose a raisonnable range for the parameters above.